# Session not updating after some ajax call requests

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am updating a session using an ajax call.

**PHP**

```
public function mymethod() 
{
    //Session Increament
    $addrowcount=1;
    $addrowcount +=$this->session->userdata('row');
    $this->session->set_userdata('row', $addrowcount);
    echo $addrowcount;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.ajax({url: "myurl.com/mycontroller/mymethod/",dataType: "json", async: false, success: function(data){}});
```

But the session is not updating or not getting increased after 20 to 23 ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether session library loading in controller or not and then try below PHP code.

```
public function mymethod() 
{ 
  //Session Increament
  $addrowcount=1;
  $addrowcount +=$this->session->userdata('row');
  $session_data=array('row' => $addrowcount);
  $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
  echo json_encode($session_data);
}
```

Comment: thanku @katamaraju for your response but i do not want to pass session value in ajax response. I am increasing session(row)+1 because after that i am fetching data from array according to ID.

Comment: can you advise me a different approach or alternative of sessions